How to change an anchor link’s smooth scroll speed js
how to make it so that when you click on an anchor link, it smoothly scrolls to the desired block.
I already use scroll-behavior: smooth; but I need that to be even smoother. To increase the time for which the page will scroll from the link to the block. How to do it using CSS or JS and without JQuery?

The above question has answers for various different techniques (despite being tagged with jQuery), it should cover what you need.

look into the lenis - smooth scroll library
